# Where did QT install to?

Tags: qt, c++, clion

I am trying to set up a qt project in CLION. I installed qt using these commands

```
sudo apt-get install qtcreator
```

and

```
sudo apt-get install qtdeclarative5-dev
```

When you create a qt application in clion you have to set a QT CMake prefix path. That is the path I am trying to find. I can't seem to find it in any directory.

Answer (score 0):

You are probably looking for this

```
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qtcreator/
```

The packages filelists are online
https://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/amd64/qtcreator/filelist
here you can find see which files get installed.

You can list the files of an installed package

```
dpkg-query -L qtcreator
```

And if it is not installed, you can download the deb package and list it's contents

```
apt download qtcreator
dpkg --contents *.deb
```

The last resort option is to `find` through all directories, or use the `locate` function.

```
find / -name qtcreate
```

where you can limit the directories searched and find more matches with this

```
find /usr/lib -name qtcreate*
```